# How to set Puppet to not manage any files not in source?

Tags: puppet

I'd like to overwrite some of the files in a directory:

```
file {
  ensure  => directory,
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/my_module/my_directory',
  mode    => '0600',
  recurse => true,
}
```

However, this changes the mode of *every* file in the directory. Since most of the files (thousands, changing every day) should be handled by another application, how can I tell Puppet to **leave all files not in `source` alone?** I can't use `ignore` because that requires that I know in advance the names (or at least globs) of files I don't want to manage.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for `recurse => remote` [[ref]](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/type.html#file-attribute-recurse), which instructs puppet to only manage the files in the destination that come from the the source.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [source_permissions](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/type.html#file-attribute-source_permissions) parameter. Of course this assumes that you can set appropriate permissions in the source repository.

Comment: That looks promising; I'll give it a try.